# How to do a clean windows 10 install after messing up bootloader with linux

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation, dualboot

So I have a new laptop with no important data. I installed windows and then I installed Linux mint in dual boot, but the laptop had no good drivers for linux mint and I tried removing Linux mint from the Ssd of the laptop. This resulted in a mess and somehow I broke my partition system, I tried using gparted live to fix it but ended up broking windows 10 bootloader, so now I don't have windows nor Linux.

I want to install windows 10 from a bootable flash drive and completely reset the Hdd, I don't mind losing data, since laptop is new.

I heard it can be done using the command prompt in the installation with the command: clean (for disk 0). IS that right?

Comment: Use FDISK or even the Windows 10 install to delete all partitions prior to install and then let Windows 10 bulid its 3 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

First potential method: boot Ubuntu Live media (Ubuntu works with a computer not booting due to malformed boot partitions) and open the terminal.
Type
`sudo fdisk /dev/[sda1]`*
then keep pressing `d` (to delete all of your partitions).
Then (just in case it's corrupted or otherwise problematic), clear your partition table by pressing `g`** or press `o` if your table was mbr. Type `w` to save your changes, and congrats, your disk is clean (for this purpose - don't use this method to remove data).
Once you do that, restart your computer (`shutdown now`), ensuring your live media is inserted, and Windows Live media should boot and create its own Windows Boot Manager partition.
You can then try to dual boot Mint again but this time go into "Advanced Settings" (I think the option is called "Something Else") in the startup wizard and make sure everything looks right so you don't mess up your disk again.

If you don't want to get Ubuntu Live media, you can try booting Windows and then pressing SHIFT-F10 to enter a command prompt. Create a new boot partition with these commands (taken from [this microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/accidentally-deleted-windows-10-boot-partition-how/181745f9-3303-4968-9851-5c213db9c89c)):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk N (N refers to the disk which contains the deleted the EFI System partition)
list partition
create partition efi
format quick fs=fat32
list partition
list volume (find the volume letter which belongs to the installed Windows OS)
exit (exit diskpart)
bcdboot M:\windows (M refers to the volume letter of installed Windows OS)
```

If you are dropped into Windows Advanced/Boot settings, then you can navigate your way to a command line through `Repair Computer option > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt`. If your screen just goes black, you can try to make your way to the settings by turning your computer on and then off when you see the windows icon 2-4 times (in theory you should be given that page by the 3rd restart). Once you are in the command line, try the above commands. If that doesn't work, I would highly recommend going the Linux way and using the fdisk approach I laid out in the beginning.

If neither of the above 2 methods work, consider not using Windows altogether and fully coming over to *the Linux Side*.

*your disk name may be different, it will likely start with sd or nvme0n (make sure you choose the right disk as your USB will also show up - you can acquire the correct name through `fdisk --list` or `lsblk`)

**Use `g` if your disk uses a GPT table - the table type can be determined through the `p` command, under "Disklabel type"